# Automorphisms of nilpotent groups of class two

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there any article that help me study automorphisms of nilpotent groups of class two with cyclic center? 
In "[Odd order nilpotent groups of class two with cyclic centre](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700016724), Y. K. Leong (1974)" there is a presentation of nilpotent groups of class two with cyclic center. How can I find the structure of automorphisms of these groups by using this presentations?

Comment: Automorphisms of class 2 nilpotent groups with cyclic centers are not difficult to describe.  For example, the case of Heisenberg groups is treated here: /http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/repns/notes_2014-15/05_finite_heisenberg_ssw.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Khukhro has two books on automorphisms. They might be helpful.

Khukhro, E. I. p-automorphisms of finite p-groups. London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 246. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1998. xviii+204 pp. ISBN: 0-521-59717-X

Khukhro, Evgenii I. Nilpotent groups and their automorphisms. De Gruyter Expositions in Mathematics, 8. Walter de Gruyter & Co., Berlin, 1993. xiv+252 pp. ISBN: 3-11-013672-4